# SQL grouping query question; evaluating a group of rows based on the value of one field

Tags: sql, row

I've got table vendorparts that lists all my parts and their vendor(s). Parts with multiple vendors have multiple records in this table. I'm trying to write a query that only returns the partid, and vendor of parts that do not have a default vendor assigned.

```
Partid      Vendor     Defaultflag
1           A          1
2           B          0
2           C          0
3           D          0
3           E          0
3           F          1
4           G          0
```

I would like to return the following:

```
Partid      Vendor
2           B
2           C
4           G
```

I'm obviously having issues with partid 3 and getting the query to see it as having a default vendor assigned.

Comment: I don't get what you want your query to return. There isn't a row for 2A, so why do you want it returned?

Comment: Sorry: I meant return 2B, 2C, and 4G

Comment: "Why not 3D and 3E?"

Because vendor F is the default vendor for partid 3. Since partid 3 has a default vendor...I don't care about it in this case.

Comment: O I C - there's no default vendor at all for 2 & 4.

Answer (score 4):

And the null-left-join method:

```
SELECT vp0.Partid, vp0.Vendor
FROM VendorParts AS vp0
LEFT JOIN VendorParts AS vp1 ON vp1.Partid=vp0.Partid AND vp1.Defaultflag=1
WHERE vp1.Partid IS NULL
```

Comment: For certain SQL servers, this method is much quicker than using a subquery.

Answer (score 2):

You can try something like

```
DECLARE @VendorParts TABLE(
        Partid INT,
        Vendor VARCHAR(10),
        Defaultflag INT
)
INSERT INTO @VendorParts SELECT  1,'A',1 
INSERT INTO @VendorParts SELECT  2,'B',0 
INSERT INTO @VendorParts SELECT  2,'C',0 
INSERT INTO @VendorParts SELECT  3,'D',0 
INSERT INTO @VendorParts SELECT  3,'E',0 
INSERT INTO @VendorParts SELECT  3,'F',1 
INSERT INTO @VendorParts SELECT  4,'G',0

SELECT *
FROM    @VendorParts vp
WHERE    NOT EXISTS (
                        SELECT  1 
                        FROM    @VendorParts 
                        WHERE   Partid = vp.Partid 
                        AND     Defaultflag = 1
                    )
```

Output

```
Partid      Vendor     Defaultflag
----------- ---------- -----------
2           B          0
2           C          0
4           G          0
```

Comment: I need it to be dynamic though, as I have several thousands parts in my inventory.

Comment: Could you please explain? Your comment does not make sense?

Comment: I need the query to evaluate a pre-existing table containing 8,030 records. It appears like your method is inserting predefined values into a new table to query against.

Comment: This is purely an Example Statement. **I would rather hate having to insert more than 10 entries into an explanetory example...** I have a table, *(DECLARE @Table VAR as example table)* with some values *(INSERT INTO yadayadayada)*, then we need some query...

Comment: @user324575: the query is just the `SELECT` at the bottom. The rest is setting up your example data.

Comment: Pardon me for complicating things on a Friday then. In that case...the select statement at the bottom works beautifully. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Use an inner select to find the parts who don't have a default vendor. This is the parts that have `MAX(Defaultflag)` = 0 when grouped by `partid`. You can then join this back to the original table to get all the rows. Here's the full query:

```
SELECT T2.Partid, T2.Vendor
FROM (
    SELECT Partid
    FROM Table1
    GROUP BY Partid
    HAVING MAX(Defaultflag) = 0
) T1
JOIN Table1 T2
ON T1.PartId = T2.PartId
```

Result:

```
2, 'B'
2, 'C'
4, 'G'
```

Answer (score 0):

something like

```
select 
 partid, 
 vendor 
from 
 vendorparts 
where 
 partid not in (
  select 
    partid 
   from 
    vendorparts 
   where 
    defaultflag = 1
 );
```